# Web server file sniffing

Tags: appsec, web-application, attacks

What is it called when a user tries several attempts to figure out the files and folder structure on a web server?

For example, the attacker will run `http://example.com/test.jpg` to determine if `test.jpg` exists or not before commencing on other kind of attacks?

Answer (score 4):

The proper term for it is [Forced (or Forceful) Browsing](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forced_browsing).

Answer (score 2):

w3af calls this [URL Fuzzing](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/plugin-descriptions.php#urlFuzzer). Nikto also does this to some degree by looking for common files and directories such as `/phpmyadmin` and `/info.php`.

Comment: That's not really so common...

Comment: Fuzzing is usually used to refer to trying a range of likely inputs as parameters in the URL or input fields, whereas the topic in the question is forceful browsing, as AviD described.

Comment: -1 for inaccuracy.  AviD's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

- http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/425.html
- http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246953/Predictable-Resource-Location